# Assigning a returned List from a method Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to return a List from the `test` method, I see that there are two options to do this. (`Option 1` and `Option 2` in the below code snippet).
I would like to know which of these two is a preferred OPTION and the reason for it (if possible).

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String a[]) {
        //OPTION 1
        List<Double> outer = new ArrayList<Double>(test());

        //OPTION 2
        List<Double> temp = test();
        if(temp != null && temp.size() > 0) {
            for(Double entry: temp) {
                System.out.println("entry = " + entry);
            }
        }
    }

    public static List<Double> test() {
        List<Double> inner = new ArrayList<Double>();
        inner.add(123.0);
        inner.add(234.0);
        return inner;
    }
}
```

Comment: *I would like to know what is the preferred OPTION* the preferred option for what ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question clearly?

Comment: @ShreyasChavan I think OP is referring to the comments, option 1 and option 2, for using the return value of `test()`. OP, option 2. I've never seen option 1 used, and can't think of a reason why you *would* do that.

Comment: I don't think there's any reason to use Option 1 really, it's just extra work

Comment: You can use any OPTION, neither of them is preferred.

Comment: Afaik, option 1 would make a shallow copy,  while option 2 is a reassignment. They do different things.

Answer (score 1):

Option 2 is better. Option 1 is a constructor that allows you to create a `List` and initialize it so that it starts with the values in a existing `Collection`. The first option is a straight-up, standard `List` assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a specific use case, Option 2 is better because you just assign the returned list to the variable `temp`.

In the first case, even though you can just pass the result of `test()` in the constructor, internally it has to copy all the values returned by `test()` into your newly created list `outer`, which is a overhead and also **you have two copies of the same list** now.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is pretty simple:
Opt1 creates a copy of the list generated by `test()` and assigns the copy to `outer`. Opt2 assigns by value. This means the list created by `test()` is directly assigned to `outer`. Whether to use Opt1 or Opt2 depends upon circumstances. In this case Opt2 would be more efficient, since the unnecessary copy-operation falls away. The copy would be necessary if for example the list would exist before calling `test()` and would only be modified int `test()` and wouldn't be used as read-only.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the only reason one would want to use the first option is to ensure that the `List` is indeed an `ArrayList`. But, in the rest of your code, all you are doing is iterating through this list. So you are not really using any feature that is particularly biased in favor of an `ArrayList`.

Therefore, I would say that option 2 is better.

1. It performs the same as option 1
2. It is more readable.
3. It does not waste any time *converting* to an `ArrayList` (which, by the way, is unnecessary because the `test()` method returns the list `inner`, which is an `ArrayList` to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any OPTION, neither of them is preferred. What is really preferred is use classes, properties, objects, non-static methods

```
public class Test {

    List<Double> inner = new ArrayList<>();

    public Test(){
       init();
    }

    public static void main(String a[]) {
        //OPTION 3
        new Test().execute();
    }

    public void execute() {
        for (Double entry: inner) 
            System.out.println("entry = " + entry);                            
    }

    public void init() {
        inner.add(123.0);
        inner.add(234.0);
    }
}
```